# Django login, next url redirect to external links

Tags: django, security, authentication

One application was allowing redirection to external links after login using the next parameter, for instance, if I'm login with `https://myawesomeapp.com/en/auth/login?next=http://google.be` I would be redirected to Google. The issue is fixed using `is_safe_url` function (from `django.utils.http`) and I also should use built-in LoginView from Django.

My question is: Is it a security breach? What an hacker can achieve with that breach?

Answer (score 1):

1. Hackers can make fake website looks like yours, and send somebody links like https://myawesomeapp.com/en/auth/login?next=https://myawesomeappp.com and user can be shure that he is still on your site. User can share credentials with hackers this way.
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting

Comment: How does hacker get back the credential this way ? you mean with a second login page ?

Comment: Exactly. They can copy design of yours and show message like "smth went wrong, please try login again"

Comment: hacker doesn't need to redirect to his website for that, he can do it in the first place, it's a common fishing attack. What would be de benefice for him to go to the real site first ?

Comment: Maybe bad example. To use bad link in the first place, hacker must register similar domain name